# Checking whether value exists in results of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns a list of IDs for a particular set of generators I want to be able to then use the results of this stored procedure as part of another query.

Can I write a query like:

```
select * from table where id in (exec dbo.storedprocedurename)
```

Comment: One way is to insert the proc results into a table variable or temp table for use in the query. See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for these and other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using table variable and `JOIN` you can achieve this. Store the procedure result into the table.

```
DECLARE @ProcOutput TABLE (Id INT);

INSERT INTO @ProcOutput (Id)
EXEC [dbo].[storedprocedurename]

SELECT T.* 
FROM Table T
JOIN @ProcOutput O ON O.Id = T.Id
```

If the procedure returns multiple entries, according to the output you can re-design the table's schema.

Comment: Worth noting that the table in you `INSERT` the dataset into needs to have the same definition as the data returned from the SP.

Answer (score 0):

If your output of procedure is 2 columns then you may try this:

```
    INSERT INTO MyTable  
    (  
         Col1,  
         Col2  
    )  
    EXEC [dbo].[storedprocedurename]

    GO
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT Col1 from Mytable)
```